# facing issue with createFile2 API in release build

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Below code works fine with debug build but with release createFile2 returns errorcode 87 i.e invalid_parameters.

path is same for debug as well as release build.

```
Host_IO::FileRef fileHandle;
#ifdef WIN_UNIVERSAL_ENV
    CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS params;
    params.dwFileAttributes = (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS);
    params.lpSecurityAttributes = 0;
    params.hTemplateFile = 0;
    params.dwFileFlags = 0;
    params.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
    fileHandle = CreateFile2((LPCWSTR)wideName.data(), (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE), 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, &params);
#else
    fileHandle = CreateFileW ( (LPCWSTR)wideName.data(), (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE), 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS,
                               (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS), 0 );
#endif

    if ( fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) XMP_Throw ( "Host_IO::Create, cannot create file", kXMPErr_InternalFailure );;

    CloseHandle ( fileHandle );
```

Comment: This isn't real code because there's no error code checking. You can't tell what the error code is because you never ask for it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my guess is they replaced the call to `XMP_Throw()` with one that printed `GetLastError()`. I looked through the XMP SDK source and it does not call `GetLastError()` in its exception system.

Comment: @David, actually I had added GetLastError call while debugging and found out that it's returning 87 as error code while copy pasting this code I some how removed it.

Comment: Asking us to look at code that isn't what you have is counter productive

Answer (score 1):

`CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS` begins with a `dwSize` field; you **must** initialize that properly to `sizeof (CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS)`, just like every other Windows API structure with a `dwSize` field. (You should also zero-initialize the rest of the structure, just to be safe.)